# Is my router capped to 11 MB/s?

Tags: router, lan, data-transfer, wired-networking

My router [Dlink DSL 2640t](http://www.sysnetcenter.com/documents/dlink_dsl2640t_ds.pdf) is giving me headaches. I can't get past 11 megabytes per second through wired LAN transfers. I've tried with different cables and network adapter settings with no results.

[This datasheet](http://www.sysnetcenter.com/documents/dlink_dsl2640t_ds.pdf) shows wireless transfer numbers, but I don't know which data might correspond to wired data transfer.

Please enlight me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bandwidth specs on your router's spec sheet are in `Megabits Per Second`. One `byte` contains eight `bits`. To calculate the number of `Megabytes Per Second`, the unit of measure you are reporting, simply divide the `Megabits Per Second` spec by `8`.

Your router only has `100Mbps` ports. `100Mbps` is roughly `12.5MB/s`. `11MB/s` of throughput (what you are getting) is *very* normal; `12.5MB/s` cannot be reached due to overhead and other factors.

To get around this without purchasing a new router, you simply need a gigabit switch (~`125Mb/s` theoretical bandwidth). Plug the switch into one of the router's `LAN` ports and then connect your devices into the switch instead of the router.

Example of a gigabit switch: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=33-122-140&IsVirtualParent=1

Note that Gigabit switches are also commonly labled as `10/100/1000` switches and/or `1Gpbs` switches.

Comment: Are there wireless access points or wireless switches that can transfer at least 30 Mb/s locally and still work with my current router?

Comment: Wireless bandwidth is generally horrible. `30 Megabytes per second` is pretty ambitious. I would look into getting an Ethernet cable run instead of relying on wireless.

Comment: Some of the very latest equipment that supports the 802.11ac standard will be able to support a much higher speed than the current router, however it would be expensive to replace the wireless access point, and all the devices connecting to it. You would be better using the solution above of adding a Gigabit switch to the network to connect the devices together.

Comment: Also worth noting that higher bandwidth requires higher frequencies, which in turn reduces range and makes line-of-sight more important. The latest VR wireless adapters need to carry so much bandwidth / are such a high frequency that you can block the signal with your hand. It's a significant issue.